# How to checkout between git branches while one has a directory and the other has a submodule under the same name and path?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-checkout

In a large git repo, I need to maintain an old branch that has a directory named NAME in its root dir. Somewhere along the way, git submodules were introduced to the project so that the directory became a submodule, and the submodule's name was defined NAME for consistency.

Now, when working on the current branch - NewBranchWithSubmodule, upon checkout to the old OldBranchWithDir, I get the following message:

```
user$ git checkout OldBranchWithDir
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
       NAME/file
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

I've read about similar issues here, but none of which solved the issue sufficiently enough.

what is the proper way to checkout or to maintain such condition? (assuming a rename or moving the dir isn't an option)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Switching between branches with submodules and trees recorded at the same path is annoying enough that the right way to do it is to set up a separate work tree for the old branches that have the abandoned setup there, your case is

```
git worktree add ../OldBranchWithDir
```